# Slim Framework PHP - block routes access to users in some conditions

Tags: php, slim

I'm using `Slim Framework` v3 for PHP and here is the code I use in a class to create my API:

```
public function __construct( ) {
    $this->slim = new \Slim\App;
    $this->init();
    $this->slim->run();
}

private function init () {
    $this->slim->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
        // my code ...
        return $response;
    });
    $this->slim->get('/getElements', array($this, 'getElements'));
    $this->slim->get('/getElements2', array($this, 'getElements2'));
    // and more...
}

public function getElements ( $request, $response, $args ) {
    // my code ...
}

public function getElements2 ( $request, $response, $args ) {
    // my code ...
}
```

In some conditions I need to restrict APIs access to users, so in the case above I need to return a `response` with error when they try to access the application routes.
So, users will receive an error when trying to access `getElements`, `getElements2` and all other routes.

I have been thinking to put some code in `init()` function and block user there, but what code can I use to do that?

Also, another way to do that would be by putting some code for each route callback and doing something like this:

```
public function getElements ( $request, $response, $args ) {
   echo json_encode(array(
      'error' => array(
         'msg' => "MESSAGE...",
      ),
   ));
   return $response;

   // my code ...
}
```

but I have many routes and prefer avoiding that.

Any idea?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I need to access the `$request` object before deciding whether a user should be blocked or not.

Thanks

Comment: This is one of the many uses of Middleware... http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved by doing this:

```
if ( !$check ) {
  return $response->withStatus(403);
}
```

in my `$this->slim->add()` function.